# Set connection time out with javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, soap, restful-url

I have an URL for which I am trying to set connection time out for 10 seconds.
Code snippet :-

```
WebTarget t=null;
Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .hostnameVerifier(<HostNameVerifier>)
                .sslContext(<SSLContext>)
                .build();
        client.register(<credentials for url>); 
        t = c.t(url);
```

From different sources, I have found the solution like below.

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 2000);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 500);
```

But both ***ClientConfig*** and ***ClientProperties*** is a utility of **org.glassfish.jersey.client** package. 
I have a limitation to use this.

Can anyone suggest here how to set connection timeout without using ClientConfig and ClientProperties.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use String values instead of `ClientProperties` constants:

```
        client.property("jersey.config.client.connectTimeout", 500);
        client.property("jersey.config.client.readTimeout", 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for information. But this did not help me also.  Gives "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder"  error. That is because jersey library is not imported and I cannot import also as I have a limitation with that. Can you please suggest me here the way forward

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation do you use?

Comment: I am using jax-rs 2.1 . That's what you meant right ? My use case is to validate incoming rest url whether it is reachable or not. If not then in that case provide time out to avoid Web UI freeze.

Comment: JAX-RS is a spec which has different implementations. Jersey is one of them.

Comment: Now I am trying to achieve same by using jersey client and common APIs. But with this I am facing a new exception like JerseyClientBuilder cannot be instantiated.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 12 more
Can you guide me here

Comment: Client client=ClientBuilder.newClient();
  client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 500);
  client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 2000);
  target=client.target("<IP>");
  response=target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
  System.out.println("Response : "+response);

Comment: I think ```guava``` is in ```jersey-client``` dependencies list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just in newer versions of JAX-RS (it says 'since 2.1'), but now you can do this:

```java
ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(3, SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(1, SECONDS)
    .build()
    .target(...)
```